# Get string of not matching items in list

Tags: c#, list

I'am comparing 2 `List<string>` wether the first list does contain an `string` that is not on the second `List`

This code works fine:

```
var onlyInXML = xmlList[i].columns.Except(rowAndTables[xmlList[i].table]);
                        if (onlyInXML.Any()) {
                            //Console.Write the not matching item here                      
                        }
```

I want to get the string, which is not matching. how do i do that ?

Comment: Hi @NameGuy, can you please provide us input data and expected output

Comment: Just two List<string> Lists.. i expect a string.

Comment: What do you mean by **not matching**?

Comment: @Ammar if list1 does contain an string, which is NOT is list2.

Comment: `Except` function will return an `IEnumerable` that contains all entities that are in its first `IEnumerable` and not in its second `IEnumerable`, so `onlyInXML` is of type `IEnumerable<string>` not a `string`, if you want to build a `string` out of it, you can use [Aggregate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate) function

Comment: refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way:

```
List<string> listOfStrings1 = new List<string>() { "abc", "def", "ghi", "lmn" };
List<string> listOfStrings2 = new List<string>() { "abc", "def", "lmn" };
List<string> listOfNotContainedStrings = listOfStrings1.Where(x => listOfStrings2.Contains(x) == false).ToList();
```

Comment: `.Where(x => !listOfStrings2.Contains(x))`

Comment: `.Except(listOfStrings2).ToList()` ??

Comment: @Prasad Telkikar: `Except` has a side effect: it *removes duplicates*, e.g. `new [] {"A", "A", "B", "C"}.Except(new [] {"C"})` will return `{"A", "B"}`; please, note that *second* (duplicate) `"A"` is removed

Comment: @DmitryBychenko, thanks for your comment. Today I learnt alternative of `Except()` where I need keep duplicates.